# Поиск файла с наименьшим количеством слов

Tags: linux

Как найти и вывести на экран имя файла с наименьшим количеством слов в файле?

Comment: Видимо пробежаться по списку файлов в цикле. с помощью `wc` получить кол-во слов и найти минимальный ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Зайдите из консоли в каталог с файлами и выполните данную команду:

```
ls --file-type | grep -v '/$' | xargs wc -w | sort -g | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Открываешь файл, считаешь количество пробелов +1 и запоминаешь где-нибудь эту пару (имя файла-число слов), береш другой файл и делаешь то же самое. Если число слов меньше чем то которое ты запомнил на предыдущем шаге, то заменчешь имя файла и новый минимум и так далее..